# Почему я получаю разные md5 хэши?

Tags: php, post, curl, md5

Доброго времени!

Формирую `POST` запрос и отправляю его на другой `URL`. В запросе содержится сформированный `md5` хэш. Проблема в том, что имея одинаковые значения я получаю разные хэши. Почему так происходит?

**Запрос:**

```
$merchant_password = "password";
    $merchant_name = "Name merchant";
    $amount = "100";
    $date = "2017-06-09 11:20:16";
    $id_transfer = "f191a923-6311-47c8-bc38-04851355ae68";
    $fee = "30";


    $hash_string2=
         $amount.':'
        .$merchant_password.':'
        .$date.':'
        .$id_transfer;

    $hash2=strtoupper(md5($hash_string2));

    // Send POST request

    $url = "http://example.com/post.php";  

    $post_data = array (  
        "amount" => $amount,
        "fee" => $fee,  
        "method" => "ADV Cash",
        "merchant_name" => $merchant_name,
        "status" => "Confirmed",
        "date" => $date,
        "id_method_transaction" => $id_transfer,
        "ballance" => "123",
        "hash" => $hash2
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    // указываем, что у нас POST запрос  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
    // добавляем переменные  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);  

    $output = curl_exec($ch);  

    curl_close($ch);  

    echo $output; 

    }else{

    }
```

**Обработчик запроса:**

```
<?php
// строка, которую будем записывать

$merchant_password = "password";

    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $fee = $_POST['fee'];
    $method = $_POST['method'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $id_method_transaction = $_POST['id_method_transaction'];
    $ballance = $_POST['ballance'];
    $merchant_name = $_POST['merchant_name'];
    $id_transfer = $_POST['id_transfer'];
$hash = $_POST['hash'];

$hash_string=
         $amount.':'
        .$merchant_password.':'
        .$date.':'
        .$id_transfer;

    $user_hash=strtoupper(md5($hash_string));

// открываем файл, если файл не существует,
//делается попытка создать его
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");

// записываем в файл текст
fwrite($fp, $amount . ' ' . $fee . ' ' . $method . ' ' . $status . ' '. $date . ' '. $id_method_transaction . ' '. $ballance . ' '. $merchant_name . ' ' .$id_transfer . ' ' . $hash . ' // user hash - ' . $user_hash);

// закрываем
fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Результат выполнения запроса:**

> 100 30 ADV Cash Confirmed 2017-06-09 11:20:16 f191a923-6311-47c8-bc38-04851355ae68 123 Name merchant  5F8D58C795D11BE3EB868470F1A8A18E // user hash - 8603190AF8C222161DDD7C6A78BED5E2

Благодарен за любую помощь или направление!

Comment: Который из хешей получается разным? Который вы отправляете или который записываете?

Comment: удостоверьтесь, что строки от которых хэш считается идентичны. потом удостоверьтесь, что кодировка обоих php-файлов совпадает.

Comment: @teran кодировка php-файлов тут при чем? Тут же вроде только латиница. Не думаю что кто-то станет UCS2, например, использовать

Comment: @tutankhamun там конкатенация с двоеточием есть, в utf-8 и 16 или 1251 разные значения ведь будут.

Comment: @teran Ну в UTF-16 действительно будет отличие. Но что-то мне кажется что в UTF-16 исходники никто не держит. Возможно я не прав

Comment: @tutankhamun да были тут уже вопросы, которые свелись к разной кодировке файлов за последние пол года не единожды.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $id_transfer = $_POST['id_transfer'];

Найдите, пожалуйста, в отправляемых данных id_transfer. Его там нет.

С NULL'ом вместо id_transfer как раз наблюдаемый хэш и получается.

Следовательно, вы не читаете даже самое банальное, что можно придумать - сообщения вашего лучшего друга, языка программирования. Если вы не читаете предупреждения интерпретатора, то чему вообще удивляться?